# How to showDialog in FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, showdialog

In Flutter,
I used FutureBuilder to display data from API.
I would like to popup an error dialog when there's error.

However, it throws error when I called showDialog()

```
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

Here's my code

```
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: xxx,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          //DO SOMETHING

        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          //TODO: Show Error

          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Text("Error"),
                  content: Text("HAHAHA"),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text("No"),
                    ),
                    FlatButton(
                        child: Text("Yes")
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              }
          );

          return Container();

        } else {
          //DO SOMETHING
        }
      },
```

Please help to advise how could I showDialog in FutureBuilder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can not call setState, navigate or showDialog while build method is building widget. so, we can wait for a microsecond and meanwhile build method complete building widget, so we can show dialog.

Create a method like below.

```
showError() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds: 1));
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Error"),
            content: Text("HAHAHA"),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("No"),
              ),
              FlatButton(child: Text("Yes")),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
```

And call this method Where you want to show dialog.